# Surface Gradient

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, surfaces, curvature

How to show that
$(\vec{n}\times\nabla_s)\times\vec{n}f=\nabla_sf-(\nabla_s\cdot \vec{n})\vec{n}f,$ 
where $\nabla_s$ is the surface gradient operator, $f$ is a scalar function and $\vec{n}$ is a vector.

Comment: Is $\vec n$ a unit vector? Is it constant?

Comment: $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from the vector identity
$$
(\vec A \times \vec B) \times \vec C = (\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B - (\vec B \cdot \vec C) \vec A\,,
$$
which is shown as follows in index notation: $(\vec x \times\vec y)_i=\epsilon_{ijk}x_j y_k$, where the sum over repeated indices is understood, so
$$
[(\vec A \times \vec B) \vec C]_l =\epsilon_{lim}(\epsilon_{ijk}A_j B_k)C_m =\epsilon_{iml}\epsilon_{ijk}A_jB_kC_m
$$
but $\epsilon_{iml}\epsilon_{ijk}=\delta_{mj}\delta_{lk}-\delta_{mk}\delta_{lj}$ and then indeed
$$
[(\vec A \times \vec B) \vec C]_l = (A_j C_j) B_l - (B_k C_k) A_l\,.
$$
In our case $\vec A=\vec n$, $\vec B=\nabla_s$ and $\vec C=\vec n$ so
$$
(\vec n \times \nabla_s)\times \vec n =(\vec n^2)\nabla_s - (\nabla_s\cdot \vec n) \vec n\,.
$$
Assuming $\vec n$ is a constant unit vector, this matches your formula.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your invoking the identity $(\vec A \times \vec B) \times \vec C = (\vec A \cdot \vec C)\vec B - (\vec B \cdot \vec C) \vec A$ is correct when $B = \nabla_s$, but the idea is worth thinking about, so **+1**.